# Append variable to list in Zscript

Tags: zscript

In Zscript I can create an list of 8 items

```
[VarDef, myArr(8)]
```

How do I add (push) a variable to that list?

```
[VarDef, temp, 14]
[myArr.push(temp)] // ??? there is no push command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. Not to my future self, you need to set a new variable for the array length.

(I don't think there is the Zscript equivalent of array.length.

Here's an example of creating a blank array and then filling it over a loop

```
[IButton, "Append", "stuff!",

// create array with 5 elements
[VarDef, myArr(5)]

// [Note,myArr(1),,1] // can't do! Variable has not been assigned a value

// create variable equal to array length
[VarDef, len, 5]

// create string to hold results
[VarDef, s, ""]

// loop over array
[VarSet,i,0] 
    [Loop,len,
        [VarSet,myArr(i), i * 2]
        [VarSet,s, [StrMerge, s, i, " "]]
        // [Note,i,,0.5] // show counter
        // [Note,s,,0.5] // show string value
        [VarInc,i] // increase loop counter by 1
    ]

// show results!
[Note,myArr(1),,1]
]
```